# Getting Mongoose Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**I'm trying to run this aggregations but I cannot get a result with aggregation option parameter, what is wrong ? Here is my aggregation:**

```
 var  coupons = couponModel.aggregate(
        [
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    from: "campaigns",
                    localField: "campaignId",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "campaigns"
                }
            },
            { "campaignId": { "$in": campaignsIds } },
        ],
        {
            allowDiskUse: true,
            explain: true
        }
    );
```

Also Try Different Structure:

```
 couponModel.aggregate(
        [
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    from: "campaigns",
                    localField: "campaignId",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "campaigns"
                }
            },
            { "campaignId": { "$in": campaignsIds } },
        ],
        function(err,result) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            // Result is an array of documents
            console.log(result);
        }
    )
```

Comment: Try `{ $match: { "$in": campaignsIds } }` instead of `{ "campaignId": { "$in": campaignsIds } }`

Comment: Thanks @Veeram it works!

Answer (score 1):

When using mongoose you cannot pass an object as the second parameter of `aggregate()`. Instead you must use mongoose functions. Also, in the second object of your pipeline you forgot to specify the aggregation stage. So your code would look like this:

```
var  coupons = couponModel.aggregate(
        [
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    from: "campaigns",
                    localField: "campaignId",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "campaigns"
                }
            },
            { $match: { "campaignId": { "$in": campaignsIds } } }
        ]
    )
    .allowDiskUse(true)
    .explain(true);
```